# How to fix Storable version discrepancy of a DBI Proxy connection?

Tags: perl, dbi, storable

I got a connection test script that is run on my client system and is calling a Perl DBI Proxy server via

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Proxy:$dbiproxy;dsn=$dsn", "$user","$pass",{ PrintError => 1}) || ($errmsg = "ERROR on connect");
```

When running the script it will fail stating

```
connect('hostname=***;port=2001;dsn=dbi:Oracle:***','***',...) failed: Cannot log in to DBI::ProxyServer: Unexpected EOF from server at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/RPC/PlClient.pm line 79.
```

The log on the DBI Proxy server reads

```
Wed Dec 15 14:47:47 2015 err, Child died: Storable binary image v2.7 more recent than I am (v2.6) at blib/lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into blib/lib/auto/Storable/thaw.al) line 363, at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.0/RPC/PlServer/Comm.pm line 179
```

So I checked the Perl and Storable module version numbers of the two systems and the DBI proxy server seems to be rather outdated:

```
source: perl 5.10.1, storable 2.20, storable 2.7 (binary), Debian 6.0
target: perl 5.8.0 , storable 2.13, storable 2.6 (binary), RHEL 3
```

The problem is that I can not update the module/perl version of the target system, so I thought I could simply lower the utilized client version by modifying the /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/RPC/PlServer/Comm.pm file and change the line

```
require Storable;
```

to

```
use Storable 2.13;
```

but this will result in the same error as above. I also tried to use Storable 2.13 directly in my Perl test-script, but that does not change anything, either.

When googling this I could not find any solution, only confirmation that this version discrepancy can be a problem. Increasing the DBI_TRACE level on the client side also did not reveal anything new. Frankly I don't know what to try next and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `use Storable 2.13;` will simply croak if the version is less than 2.13; it won't actually use a different version of the module.

Comment: The `use` means 'use at least 2.13'.  Unless you only have '2.13' installed, it will use a later version.  Also, the part causing trouble is the binary versions (2.6 vs 2.7).  You need to find a way to get a more modern version of Perl (or at least Storable, and presumably DBI and DBI::ProxyServer) onto the system. Perl 5.8.0 is from July 2002; Perl 5.10.1 is from August 2009. They're both rather old. I think you should look into installing a newer version of Perl and DBI etc on both systems — perhaps Perl 5.22.0, even, not overwriting the stuff in `/usr/bin` etc; in an alternative location.

Comment: Failing that, you need to establish which version of Storable is in the more ancient system and uninstall what is currently installed on the more modern system and install just the archaic version instead.  And then rebuild any modules that use Storable, etc.

Comment: Or port to use json instead of storable

Comment: You should bea ble to compile a newer version of stoarble (fetched from CPAN) on your target system. You might have to ether add a BEGIN-Block to load the right version of the Storable (your newly compiled Version)